# Nginx php mvc 403 forbidden

Tags: php, nginx

My nginx server is not allowing for the php files on subfolder giving a 403

I have a apache that is running ok with a .htaccess

```
{
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.[\d]{10}\.(css|js)$ $1.$2 [L]
}
```

The folder structure is like this :

```
-root
-- Classes
-- Controllers
-- Includes
-- Models
-- Views
--- Home
---- home-view.php
-Index.php
```

The index is run and open on the browser, but in a button with a link that points to \views\home\ and should load the home-view.php by a controller it's giving me a 403 forbidden, on apache all is working.

the nginx conf is :

```
root /var/www/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
server_name cityguide.com wwwcityguide.com

location / {
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?path=$1 break;
  }
  rewrite "^/(.*)\.[\d]{10}\.(css|js)$" /$1.$2 break;
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404
}
```

Comment: have you installed and provided the correct path of php in your Nginx configuration?

Answer (score 1):

If you have php-fpm simple provide path in Nginx just like below example. If not you can install php-fpm use following command

```
sudo apt-get install phpx-fpm
```

where x is version of php for example for php7.3 it should be

```
sudo apt-get install php7.3-fpm
```

Then add following line in your configuration file

```
location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }
```

Then you file looks like(considering you are using php7.3)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    . . .

    root /var/www/your folder path;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

      location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

Also, don't forget to add `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;` this line your location otherwise other routes of MVC not work for you.

Comment: location ~ \.php$ { include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name}

Comment: Also, if you want you can achive the same using fastcgi as well for that you need to add following line `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;`

Comment: just tried everything and still i get the 403 forbidden on the sub folder, on the root all seems to be working

Comment: Please check your php-fpm path and updated your configure file accordingly

Comment: nothing seems to work, i've check the fpm path all seems to be correct..if i remove the $uri / it doens give the 403, but it still doesnt load the file as apache does, maybe the htaccess that i need and did convert to nginx doesnt get run ?

Comment: Can you check what kind of error your getting in your log files